# How to save custom form field value from payment form in magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment

I am trying to save custom form filed value from payment form during place order.
I have added custom field in payment form with id **method_payment_profile_id**

```
 <div id="selectstore" style="width: 180px;">
        <select name="payment[method]" class="select input-text required-entry" 
                            data-bind="
                                attr: {id: getCode()+'_payment_profile_id'},
                                event:{ change: getSelectedValuecc()},
                                options: getCardList(),
                                optionsValue: 'value',
                                optionsText: 'type',
                                optionsCaption: $t('--Select Store--'),
                                ">
         </select>
     </div>
```

**add bellow code in js file**

```
 getData: function() {
                return {
                    'method': this.item.method,
                    'additional_data': {
                        'bankowner': $('#paytm_payment_profile_id').val()
                    }
                };
            },
            /**
             * Get value of instruction field.
             * @returns {String}
             */
            getInstructions: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
            }
```

**By event trying to get value of custom form field**

**observer code**

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer) {
        $inputParams = $this->_inputParamsResolver->resolve();
        if($this->_state->getAreaCode() != \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML){
        foreach ($inputParams as $inputParam) {
            if ($inputParam instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment) {
                $paymentData = $inputParam->getData('additional_data');
}
}
}
}
```

i am getting error on this line `$inputParams = $this->_inputParamsResolver->resolve();`